# Refreshing the pages when navigated back in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

I have two pages that I navigate to and from. One is called the MainPage which is a Pivot page and the other is an ordinary page/class called the AddNewHistoryPage. There is a function called DisplayHistory in the MainPage that I would like to call on navigation back to MainPage from the AddNewHistoryPage.

I found that there is a protected function called OnNavigatedTo. Could someone help to find a little more information, such as

1. The OnNavigatedTo function should be written in the MainPage if I want to call the DisplayHistory in the mainPage
2. what does ' base.OnNavigatedTo(e)' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your phones state when navigating to the DisplayHistory page, so when navigating back to main page your information you need retained will stay retained.

Also when using the function OnNavigatedTo that would be used on MainPage but you would have to write a statement checking which pages it was navigated from....such as DisplayHistory.
If you don't use or that write that statement, every time the page is accessed it will run that Function.

[WP7 Navigation in Depth](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Navigation-in-depth--Navigation-Framework)
This Above link helped me a lot when learning tombstoning and having to save specific things to memory ICE(In Case of Emergency).

Hope this will help you out! :)

Answer (score 1):

Keeano Martin's Link should be enough to anwser your first question.

Regarding your second question: 
'base.OnNavigatedTo(e)' calls the base classes OnNavigateTo method.
Your page inherits from a base class: 'PhoneApplicationPage'. If you do not override the OnNavigatedTo method then the base classes implementation will be called directly. When you do override a method then you should [usually] call the base class implementation (using the code you posted). If you don't do this then any code in the base classes implementation will never be run and you will probably get some unexpected behaviour.